# Executing .bat file through Win Scheduled Tasks and be able to see the progress

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to execute a .bat file through scheduled tasks. Ideally I would like to see the cmd window popup and see the progress (in a similar fashion when .bat file is manually double-clicked).

I have the scheduled task running fine and the script is executed fine as well however the cmd window does not open since the scheduled task does not trigger the cmd to open.

Is there a way to see the task has been executed, running and also see the progress?

Comment: Doesn't Scheduler have a radio box to check for 'interactive task' which should display the window.

Comment: ..I could not find any radio box for 'interactive task' but I voted you up us since you helped me to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...thanks foxdrive,

I tried to search what you recommended and coincidentally found out that the cmd window pops up automatically when the scheduled task has the radio button **"Run only when user is logged in"** checked. So I tried it and it worked.

However, to make things more interesting, the instantiated cmd window will show only if I am physically at our server machine and directly logged in. If I log in through VNC or RAdmin it simply does not show regardless if I am logged in as a designated user or not.

Thanks to all who tried to answer this post.